# Looping through 1d array to find duplicate elements

Tags: php, arrays

I need to loop through the array to find duplicate array elements and echo them. A for loop is what i need, I know that but my previous attempts just don't work to compare.

```
$array = array(3,2,1,3);
```

Comment: This will tell you which values have been duplicated: `$array1 = array(3,2,1,3); $array2 = array(); foreach($array1 as $v){if(isset($array2[$v])){++$array2[$v];}else{$array2[$v] = 1;}}echo '<pre>'.print_r($array2, TRUE).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for this:

```
$array = array(3, 2, 1, 3);
$counts = array_count_values($array);

foreach ($counts as $key => $count) {
    if ($count > 1) {
        echo sprintf('Key %s is present in the array %d times!', $key, $count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `for` loop, you can use `foreach` combined with [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$duplicates = array(); 
foreach(array_count_values($arr) as $val => $freq) {
    if($freq > 1) $duplicates[] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine array_count_values, array_filter, array_keys:

```
$array = [3, 2, 1, 3];
$duplicates = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        array_count_values($array),
        function ($i) {
            return $i > 1;
        }
    )
);
print_r($duplicates);

// results
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

Hope that helps.

[PHP: array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)
[PHP: array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
[PHP: array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)